# Linq to SQL joining two tables and populate GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview, join

I have two tables in my database, Building and Town. They look like this:

Building:

```
buildingid
buildingname
```

Town:

```
id
userid
buildingid
```

In Town there is one entry for each building a user has.

What i want is to populate a GridView for a user with a given userid. This GridView should include the buildingname and the number of buildings.
Building. I have tried this:

```
var buildings = (from Town in dc.Towns
                         join Building in dc.Buildings
                             on Town.buildingid equals Building.buildingid
                         select Building.buildingname);
        gvBuildings.DataSource = buildings;
        gvBuildings.DataBind();
```

But I don't know how to get the numbers for each building.

---

I have now been working on this for a while and a couple of your answers work. I have used this code:

```
var buildings = dc.Towns
            .Where(t => t.userid == userid)
            .GroupJoin(dc.Buildings,
                       t => t.buildingid,
                       b => b.buildingid,
                       (Town, Buildings) => new
                                                {
                                                    BuildningName = Buildings.First().buildingname,
                                                    Count = Buildings.Count()
                                                });
        gvBuildings.DataSource = buildings.ToList();
        gvBuildings.DataBind();
```

When i run this code my GridView ends up looking like this:
[image: GridView]

I need the buildings to be shown in groups, grouped by the buildingname. I have tried all of the suggestions but i cant get it to work.

Comment: number of each buildin is id of building or count of each building ?

Comment: @PranayRana To get the number I need to count each entry in Town where userid == parameterUserId and Buildingid == parameterBuildingid

Comment: it seems like you just need to add one where condition because you are already applying the inne join on building id ...

Comment: try the solution i updated my answer might work for you...

Comment: A couple of the solutions sort of works. But It does not group the results by building name. I get the GridView populated but its shown like this: barracks 1, barracks 1, barracks 1, stable 1, archery 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping:

```
var buildings = dc.Towns
                  .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
                  .GroupJoin(dc.Buildings,
                             t => t.BuildingId,
                             b => b.BuildingId,
                             (town, buildings) => new
                             {
                                 BuildingName = buildings.First().BuildingName,
                                 Count = buildings.Count
                             });
```

Keep in mind that when binding to a control you must supply a collection of type (or implementing) `IList`. This can be accomplished by calling `ToList()` on the `buildings` collection:

```
gvBuildings.DataSource = buildings.ToList();
gvBuildings.DataBind();
```

Comment: This does not group the results together. The results from this query is shown in the edited question.

Comment: @Twistar, in that case, use a simple `Join` followed by a `GroupBy`.

Answer (score 1):

check [linq differed execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

and than try the blow code might work for you

```
    var buildings = 

(from j in dc.Town 
join i in dc.Buildings
 on j.buildingId equals i.buildingId
where j.Userid = varUSerid 
group new {i, j} 
by new 
{   i.BuildingID } 
into 
g  
select new {   
  BuildingName = g.First<k=>k.BuildingName)
   , count = g.Count() } ).ToList();
    gvBuildings.DataSource = buildings; 
          gvBuildings.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var buildings = (from Town in dc.Towns
                                 join Building in dc.Buildings
                                     on Town.buildingid equals Building.buildingid
                                 into results
                                 from r in results.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 group Town by new 
                                 {
                                     r.BuildingId
                                 } into groupedResults
                                 where Town.UserID == parameteruserId
                                 select new 
                                 {
                                     BuildingName = Building.buildingname,
                                     BuildingCount = groupedResults.Count()
                                  });
```

Try this.. it should work.. i have a similar requirement..

Comment: This line: BuildingCount = Building.Count() does not work. seems like this would work if I only knew where to use the Count() statement.

Comment: Check the modified query if you need to group by BuildingId.

Comment: the line where Town.UserID == parameteruderId does not compile. It tells me: Cannot access non-static property "userid" in static "context"

Comment: Take out that line and run the code.. Does it bind the results to the datagrid

Comment: Deleted that line but there are still errors at the select statment: ambiguous invocation, also the Building.buildingname has the same error as the one above..

Comment: Can you please put the query which is working without any errors? Did the query without Grouping work correctly?

Comment: I have edited the question with the query that works, I did not get your suggestion to compile so I used RePirre's answer...

Comment: have modified my query..   group Town by new 
                                     {
                                         r.BuildingId
                                     } into groupedResults'

Answer (score 1):

```
 manDbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();

 var estimatedTotal = (  from est in db.AssignmentEstimatedMaterials
                         where est.assignment_id == Convert.ToInt32(Label_assignmentId.Text)
                         join materialdetail in db.Materials on est.material_id equals materialdetail.material_id
                         select new { est.qty,est.total_amount, materialdetail.material_name}).ToList();

    GridView_estiamte_material.DataSource = estimatedTotal;
    GridView_estiamte_material.DataBind();
```

Note, you should select individual data and it works.